# Why am I getting an Unexpected token async on node.js?

Tags: node.js, async-await

Hi,

I have this code on my server file:

```
getName(){
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        conn.query("SELECT name FROM members WHERE id=1", (err, res, fields) => {
            if (err) reject(err);

            resolve(res);
        });
    });
}

func() async {

    try{
        const data = await getName();
        console.log(data);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

but I get this error: `Unexpected token async` so I removed `async` but then I get another error saying: `Unexpected token {`

What is happening here? I have node latest version: v10.24.1

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of your anonymous async function is wrong, try to change it like this example.

```
(async function() {
  // Your code
})();
```

Also, you didn't return the promise from your `getName()` function.

```
getName() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Your code
  })
}
```

More information about [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

Comment: now it says that func is `unexpected identifier`

Comment: thanks. No errors now but Im getting an undefined as response. I have yet another error on my original code maybe?

Comment: It seems ok, try to change the query or resolve it with a hardcoded value to test.

Comment: I tried with this `function getName(){
 const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  return 'something';
 });
};` but still get undefined

Comment: I found the problem, answer updated.

Comment: now it works, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better if you use only async await and don't combine it with try and catch. That may give weird result. Try to refactor it only with async await syntax.

```
  async func(){
    const data = await getName();
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: do you care to elaborate a little more please? With an example maybe.

Comment: What happens when you do 
async func(){
  const data = await getName();
  console.log(data);
}

Comment: i get undefined

Comment: What if you return the constant in the getName()? The issue is in the first function, I guess ( as it was suggested).

Comment: I tried like this: `function getName(){  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {   return 'something';  }); };` but still get undefined

Comment: I meant writing the return before the constant, but I saw you got it already sorted out.

Comment: no quite. i still don know how to make a variable that stores all that.